# Permission denied when running go from Makefile

Tags: go, makefile

I'm experiencing some weird permission denied errors that I have no idea where could be coming from.

```
$ go run .
Hello from go
```

```
$ make run
go run .
make: go: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:2: run] Error 127
```

```
$ make run2
echo "Make says hello" ; go run .
Make says hello
Hello from go
```

```
$ cat Makefile 
run:
    go run .

run2:
    echo "Make says hello" ; go run .
```

```
$ cat main.go 
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from go")
}
```

My terminal is bash running on Ubuntu 22.04.

What is the difference between my `run` target and running go directly that can cause a permission denied error?

What's the difference between `run` and `run2` that allow it to work in one but not in the other?

EDIT: Running make with `-d` / `--trace`

```
$ make -d run
<...snip...>
 No need to remake target 'Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'run'.
 File 'run' does not exist.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'run'.
Must remake target 'run'.
go run .
make: go: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:2: run] Error 127
```

```
$ make --trace run
Makefile:2: target 'run' does not exist
go run .
make: go: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:2: run] Error 127
```

```
$ make --trace run2
Makefile:5: target 'run2' does not exist
echo "Make says hello"; go run .
Make says hello
Hello from go
```

Comment: So, what if you add `echo "foo"; ` before `go run .` in the `run` target?

Comment: Also, does it print anything "interesting" if run with `--trace`?

Comment: @kostix adding `echo "foo";` to run makes it work and returns `foo\nHello from go"`. I've added the output of running make with `-d`. I'm not sure how to run it with `--trace`.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this issue.  I'm inclined to think it arises from some combination of circumstances that has not been fully captured by the question.  Things you could try include (i) creating a fresh directory in which to work, and putting only your `Makefile` and `main.go` there; (ii) running `main.go` explicitly (`go run main.go`) instead of running all `.go` files in the directory.  Also, be sure not to have the `.go` file open in an editor when you perform a run, at least if you use the `go run .` variation.

Comment: That is very interesting. Each command under a target is supposed to be run by a separate shell instance. Looks like as if `make` sees what can be interpreted as a simple shell command, it uses some—let's call it this way—"default" shell, and when it sees what can be thought to be a script (say, two commands separated with a `;`) it spawns a new shell which somehow gets initialized in a way different from that default shell. May it be that you have tweaked `~/.bashrc` after your login session started, and you did not restart the shell you're trying your `make` runs in? That could explain it.

Comment: …That is, when a new shell is spawned, it is initialized in such a way it finds "runnable" `go`, and whatever `go` `make` sees is different. You can try to change `go run .` to `which go` and see. Well, I admit these are just shots in the dark, but still…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is due to a bug in GNU make (actually it's a bug in gnulib).  It means that you have a *directory* named `go`, in some directory on your `PATH` (before the actual directory containing the `go` executable).

So if you have a *directory* `/usr/bin/go/.` and you have `/usr/bin` on your `PATH`, you'll see this issue.

You should check your `PATH` and make sure to remove any directories that contain such subdirectories.  If you can't remove that directory from your `PATH` (it's unusual to need directories containing subdirectories on your `PATH` but I guess it's possible) and you can't rename the `go` directory to something else, you'll have to ensure that GNU make invokes a shell, by adding a special character.  Just `;` is good enough:

```
run:
         go run . ;
```

Comment: Just to note I believe this bug is fixed in the latest releases of GNU make (4.4 or higher)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're experiencing is likely due to different environment between your shell and shell executed by `Makefile`. If for example you have a shell alias for `go` this alias is not visible to `Makefile` or if you have a custom path in you're shell rc file it's not visible to `Makefile`. It's hard to guess where the difference might be.

You might want to try debug the issue by trying following in your `Makefile`:

```
echo $(PATH)
command -v go
```

and run the same commands in your shell and compare results.

Note that the default shell for `Makefile` is `/bin/sh` whereas you probably have `bash` or `zsh`.

Here's some handy defaults to configure your `Makefile` build:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS=--norc --noprofile -e -u -o pipefail -c
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same `Makefile` shell that runs both `run` and `run2`? How can `run2` work when `run` doesn't?

Comment: I can't spot any difference between the two recipes. I'd expect `run` and `run2` to behave the same.

Comment: They don't. Adding `command -v go` and `echo $(PATH)` to the run target returns the exact same values as doing it manually from the terminal.

Comment: Try adding `.PHONY: run run2` to `Makefile`.

Comment: That the shell `make` uses to execute recipes is (by default) `/bin/sh` does not prevent it from inheriting the environment of the interactive shell from which `make` is launched, whatever that is.  Environment in this sense is a process characteristic, not a shell-specific one.