# bizarre "permission denied" from make

Tags: rust, makefile, rust-cargo

I am seeing a very strange "permission denied" error from make.

```
bash:~/scratch$ which cargo
XXX/.cargo/bin/cargo
bash:~/scratch$ cargo help
Rust's package manager

Usage: cargo [+toolchain] [OPTIONS] [COMMAND]

Options:
  -V, --version             Print version info and exit
      --list                List installed commands
      --explain <CODE>      Run `rustc --explain CODE`
=== etc

bash:~/scratch$ make
which cargo
XXX/.cargo/bin/cargo
cargo help
make: cargo: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 127
```

Cargo, the rust package manager, runs perfectly from the command line but running the same commands from make gives me a persmission denied. It appears to be the same `cargo` that I am running; I've tried re-installing cargo. I think `cargo` is the problem as `rustc` or `cargo-clippy` in the same directory do run both inside and outside make.

Makefile looks like this:

```
all:
    which cargo
    cargo help
```

Comment: Might this be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73908737/permission-denied-when-running-go-from-makefile?

Comment: that clearly has nothing to do with cargo itself

Comment: Might be related and, in fact, is caused by this! Thank you very much! Dogbert